# Android notification icon not shown

Tags: android, notifications

small icon on push notification not showing on android 12 onwards

Tried to minimize the small icon size to 22dp*22dp as per google documentation. In Android 11 device it's working fine. Could someone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Notification Builder, you can use setSmallIcon and setLargeIcon property

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) ? R.drawable.ic_notification : R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Had he not mentioned that it does NOT show up the icon?